# Eigenvalues of the logarithm

Tags: matrices

For $M \in B(I,1) \subset \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbf{R})$, define

$$ \operatorname{log}(M) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac{(M-I)^k}{k}. $$

Let $\Gamma$ denote the subset of $\operatorname{M}_n(\mathbf{R})$ consisting of matrices with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ such that $|\operatorname{Im} \lambda_i| < \pi$.

I want to show that $B(I,1) \subset \operatorname{exp}(\Gamma)$. I think the best way of doing this is to show that $\operatorname{log}(B(I,1)) \subset \Gamma$. It might be easy if $M$ is diagonalizable or even trigonalizable (which is the case in $\mathbf{C}$, but not in $\mathbf{R}$, but a priori it is not the case here. I showed that $\Gamma$ is invariant by the application $M \to PMP^{-1}, ~ P \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbf{R})$ (because then $M \simeq PMP^{-1}$, and two similar matrices have the same eigenvalues) but don't see how it helps here.